# Post request don't give correct response (Android)

Tags: react-native, post, fetch, expo, fetch-api

I am new at React native expo and I am trying to convert my **ReactJS** App to
**React Native** App.

I am doing a **post** request for login :

```
 const  submitHandler = async() => {
    await fetch(`${API}/login`, {
      method: "post",
      mode:"no-cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        password: password,
      }),
    })
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.error) {
          console.log(data);
        } else  {
          console.log(data.token);
        if(data.token)
        {  AsyncStorage.setItem("jwt", data.token);
          AsyncStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data.user));
        }
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

And this is my Inputs:

```
   <TextInput
        value={email}
        onChangeText={setemail}
        placeholder="Email"
      >
</TextInput>
      <TextInput
        value={password}
        onChangeText={setpassword}
        placeholder="Password"
      >
</TextInput>
      <Button title="Login" onPress={()=>submitHandler()}></Button>
```

With empty fields it should give **{error:"...."}**
and with correct fields , it should give token along with name and id of user

but in console , i am getting undefined for both empty or correct field

API is working as it gives correct response in postman.

Comment: What is `mode:"no-cors",` used for?

Comment: I added it because I saw that in a video
Without it,it says failed to fetch.

It is used to remove cors error , as we are sending data from different port.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to transform it into a json before processing it

```js
const submitHandler = async() => {
    await fetch(`${API}/login`, {
      method: "post",
      mode:"no-cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        password: password,
      }),
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.error) {
          console.log(data);
        } else  {
          console.log(data.token);
        if(data.token)
        {  AsyncStorage.setItem("jwt", data.token);
          AsyncStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data.user));
        }
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Comment: I removed it because it says **SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input** at this line

Comment: Are you sure that the response you receiveis a well formatted JSON ?
Check with res.text() if you want to debug what's coming from your api

Comment: In Postman :

With Empty fields :
{
    "error": "Invalid Username or Password..."
}
And with correct fields:
{
    "token": ".......",
    "user": {
        "_id": ".....",
        "name": "......."
    }
}

Comment: do `.then(res => {console.log(res.status); return res.text()}).then(console.log)` after the fetch to see if the status code is okay and what is your response body

Comment: It is printing 0 and res.body is null or undefined

Comment: try again without the no-cors mode

Comment: "res.body is null or undefined " is coming from your API ? If yes there is maybe a problem with the request (If you say that the postman one works)
Postman can generate a fetch request for you: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/
You can test on your browser also, as the fetch are the same in react-native and web